# Looking to name a specific semantic relation

Tags: terminology, semantic-roles, semantics

When one makes a choice, he is faced with some alternatives: "go by car" or "go by bus"; "prefer sightseeing" or "go shopping", "buy a house" or "rent a flat", etc. These alternatives share the same hypernym (car and bus are means of transportation; sightseeing and shopping are activities; etc) and they have the tendency to exclude each other, but how would you call their *semantic* relation?

Is there anything in the literature as "alternative semantic relation" or "adversarial semantic relation"?

Edit:
I may have found my answer, the term what I'm looking for might be "co-hypernym"
https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/9244/is-there-a-term-ending-in-nym-that-signifies-terms-that-all-have-the-same-hy?rq=1

Comment: What do you mean: "adversarial semantic relation"? If it means choices exclude each other, then what is the difference between it and "alternative semantic relation"?

Comment: @TangHo I'm wondering if such a concept actually exists in the literature, and if it does, what it might be called?

Comment: go by [method of transportation] is merely an idiomatic way of expressing how one moves from one place to another. There is nothing "adversarial" about it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because This [linguistics.se] question isn't about learning English

Answer (score 0):

I would say the relationship between "go by car" (choice A) and  "go by bus" (choice B) is "mutually exclusive"

Example of mutually exclusive choices:

> You want to buy apple or orange first? (cannot be both at the same time. -- 'apple first' exclude 'orange first' )

Example of non-mutually exclusive choices:

> Do you want to buy apple or orange? (you can buy both at the same time -- 'buy apple' doesn't exclude 'buy orange')

Another example: Fighting the pandemic doesn't exclude saving the economy (you can do both at the same time)

Comment: [buy apple first or orange=not very idiomatic; buy apples first or oranges]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this function is called a disjunction, either inclusive or exclusive as in your example, where you have to choose between two disjuncts excluding each other (the either/or case).